# How use multiple parameter in Codeigniter PHP Function

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have gone through a lot off atticles on the net for possible idea on how to do this but yet I couldn't find a suitable answer, so I decided to ask.
I have a function with more than two parameters but the function is not returning anything, also there is no error message. I have other functions with one and two parameter which work perfectly but all the functions with more than two parameters are not working.
How am I supposed to pass more than two parameters in a function?

```
    function realward($par1,$par2,$par3){
        if($par1 == 01 &&  $par2 == 01 && $par3 == 01){
           echo 'Earth';
       }
       elseif($par1 == 01 && $par2 == 01 && $par3 == 02){
           echo 'Ocean';
       }

      }
```

How I called the function

```
  <?php realward($par1code,$par2code,$par3code) ?>
```

Kindly put me through. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the parameters will go trought the ifs conditions?? Try adding a echo outside the if.

Comment: I've done same with two parameters and it work. But not working with three parameters or more

Comment: It sounds like the function is called but neither of the IF conditions are being met.

Comment: I did the echo and it returns the value for the three parameters.

Comment: @faintsignal You are very right. Thanks for opening my eyes to it. Is now working

Comment: Remember `echo` and [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) are your friends. Especially when we are looking at our own code. :)

Comment: Ok, noted. Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Add an `} else { print "other")`. At the top of the function, also add:

```
var_dump($par1)
var_dump($par2)
var_dump($par3)
```

So you can see what was posted

Additionally;

`$par1 == 01` will never ever, ever, ever be `true` to my knowledge, as the triple `=` will check for type, and an int will never be e.g. `01`, but `1`

And, your function already has `echo`s in there, so change

```
<?php echo realward($par1code,$par2code,$par3code) ?>
```

to

```
<?php realward($par1code,$par2code,$par3code) ?>
```

Comment: The problem is with the condition. So, I simulated the values to meet the condition and it worked. Also, there is nothing wrong with my code is correct. The data is being supplied from the database.

Comment: No your code is incorrect regardless of anything, as I highlighted with my `ever, ever, ever`. Have you added the `else` and `var_dump`s

Comment: So what's the output of the `var_dumps`s?

Comment: string(2) "01" string(2) "02" string(2) "02"  These are the values in the database.

Comment: Then change to: `if($par1 == "01" &&  $par2 == "01" && $par3 == "01"){`, etc

Comment: What do you mean "also worked"? Try using `parseint($par1) === 1`